# Is it possible to implement conditional logic for in-app payments in iOS in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

Is there any way to implement conditional logic for payments in Swift? For example:

Say the user has agreed to have 10$ withdrawn from his bank account he connected to his app account if, on a specific day, he has not fulfilled a condition that can be tracked with the app.

If he fulfills the condition until 23:59, no money will be withdrawn. If he doesn't, at 00:00 on the next day, the 10$ are automatically withdrawn from his bank account.

I don't know of any app that does this and I'm not even sure whether an app like this would be permitted on the app store. I'm not even sure whether that's technically possible.

Would be thankful for any helpful input!

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: I'm not really looking for a code example, just want to know whether someone has seen/implemented something similar. Or knows wether its technically possible/ permitted on the App store

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Using the in-app payments system (a.k.a. iOS in-app purchases which utilise the StoreKit2 or StoreKit API) this not feasible.

Explaining how in-app purchases work would be a bit tedious.
However, to put it simply, you can basically initiate either a one-time payment request, or a recurring payment request.
In each of these scenarios, the user may obviously either make the payment or decline, about which you would get updated in code.

The closest the system comes to what you are asking for is recurring payments (technically called the **auto-renewable subscriptions**).
However there is no way to ask Apple to conditionally deduct money based on whether the user has performed some action or not.

I'm pretty sure you should not be looking at the iOS in-app purchase system as a way to do what your are looking for.

You could use 3rd-party payments.

However, whether Apple allows this, would depend on what kind of **condition** you expect the user to fulfil. If it relates to a real world service or material, then you may be able to justify it to Apple, however, if it is a digital service, lets say an app based activity, such as opening the app a given number or times, or viewing the app for a given amount of time, then I'm pretty sure this would be in violation of the Apple App Store Guidelines and they would reject your app when you submit it for review.

To be honest without understanding the use-case a little more clearly it is a bit difficult to advise you on the technical feasibility.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Clears up some confusion I have had.

I'm thinking about an app, that gives people a financial incentive to meet their goals.

For example imagine someone wants to stick to 10k steps one day. So he "bets" 10$ that he will reach the targeted amount of steps by the end of the day and if not, his staked 10$ will be deducted from his bank account.

The goal of the app is to give people "skin in the game", so they are motivated to achieve their goals.

Do you think that would be permitted? Also, are there any 3rd party payments that'd allow this?

Comment: I do not have a concrete answer but I'll tell you what I do know about this.

Comment: Let us start with 3rd party payment systems allowing this, it depends on the user's national financial systems / laws etc. In my country, India, we have a wallet app called PayTM, which deducts a fixed amount of money every time the money in the app wallet goes below a certain limit. Your scenario is kind-of similar in a way. So you'd have to check if your target country's banking system allows for such a thing.

Comment: Now, whether such an app would be permitted, I feel it sounds very loop-holey (if there is ever such a word). I personally would try to move away from the idea of betting money.
However, if you did go ahead and built such an app, the final word would be Apple's at the time of review. In my opinion this is a grey area, or maybe I do not have experience with betting apps.

Comment: Apple might get miffed because this app has possibilities of having people lose money for no reason (in my view it would be tough to determine whether a user has really completed 10K steps, but then there are betting apps that allow people to stake money on nothing but chance)

I'm really sorry to say that I cannot give you anything more concrete about this.

Maybe someone who has experience with betting apps might be able to shed more light. I only have the technical knowledge about the APIs involved and those as I mentioned do not allow you to do what you are expecting.

All the best..